# Better way to Select & Read Date in dd/mm/yy format?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, datetime, datetime-format

In earlier vb.net 2008 I used the DateTime to read the date in `dd/mm/yy` format.
I use to change the culture info to UK format. So that the date will be selected from SQL server as in `dd/mm/yy` format.

But I know it's not good to play with `CultureInfo`. Even though I used like the following manner.

Any other better Ideas for me?

```
Sub Form_Load()
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = New CultureInfo("en-GB", False)    
End Sub
```

Any other better Ideas for me? Thanks for the Ideas.

Thanks & Regards.

Comment: In what format does your SQL Server keep dates?

Comment: @abatishchev: Sql server stores dates as two 4-byte integers.  It doesn't store it in any other format.  How it is *displayed* is a different matter and unrelated to how it is stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C# you could get the date string in desired format like,

```
string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

If you want to get DateTime object from string value representing DateTime in specific culture, you can do

```
     DateTime dt = new DateTime();
                DateTime.TryParse("16/01/2011", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB"),
  System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out dt);
```

Comment: It's better to use DateTime.Today if you don't need time-part

Answer (score 2):

From DateTime to string:

```
string s = DateTime.Today.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

From string to DateTime:

```
DateTime d;
bool success = DateTime.TryParseExact("26/05/2011", "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out d);
```

Answer (score 1):

DateTime --> String

```
DateTime.Now.ToString( new CultureInfo("fr-FR", false) );
```

String --> DateTime:

The preferred method would probably be [DateTime.Parse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx)

```
dateString = "16/02/2008 12:15:12";
try 
{
     dateValue = DateTime.Parse(dateString, new CultureInfo("en-GB", false));
     Console.WriteLine("'{0}' converted to {1}.", dateString, dateValue);
}   
catch (FormatException) 
{
     Console.WriteLine("Unable to convert '{0}'.", dateString);
}
```

This way you are not changing the Culture info of the current Context. This does assume you know what the format will be beforehand though.

Comment: It's better to use `DateTime.TryParse()` to avoid exception throwing

Answer (score 1):

You can format the date using the CultureInfo, without setting the culture for the whole thread, thanks to the `IFormatProvider` interface:

```
DateTime d = DateTime.Now;
CultureInfo c = new CultureInfo("en-GB", false);
string s = d.ToString(c.DateTimeFormat);
```

This has the added advantage that you don't have any hard-coded formats, and if the user changes the localisation settings on their machine, your application will reflect their preferences.

You can use `DateTime.TryParse` to parse the date...

```
string s = "01/01/2011";
DateTime date;
if (DateTime.TryParse(s, out date))
{
    // Parsed correctly
}
else
{
    // Invalid string!
}
```

And even use an `IFormatProvider` to help `TryParse` work out the format.

```
CultureInfo c = new CultureInfo("en-GB", false);
string s = "01/01/2011";
DateTime date;
if (DateTime.TryParse(s, c.DateTimeFormat, DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
{
    // Parsed correctly
}
else
{
    // Invalid string!
}
```

Comment: I think OP doesn't need exactly en-GB culture, seems that he use it because of `DateTimeFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"`